# Vectors , finding coefficient

Tags: vectors, vector-analysis

if (x,y,z) unequal to (0,0,0) and (i + j + 3k)x + ( 3i - 3j +k)y + (-4i + 5j)z = a(xi + yj + zk), then the value of a is

Attempt:
I wrote 
$$(x+3y-4z) i + (x-3y+5z) j + (3x+y) k = a (x i + y j + z k)$$
Which gave me 
$$
x+3y-4z=ax\\
x-3y+5z=ay\\
3x+y=az
$$
Now these are 4 unknown and only 3 equations.

Also, i dont know determinant , so please suggest me another way to solve it without using determinants.

Comment: Well, my first thought is that you should use the determinant :)

Comment: You have 4 unknowns and 3 equations, so it's clearly underdetermined. But that's a feature of the original problem as well: if you have one solution, then multiplying each of $x, y, z$ with any non-zero number gives you another solution. So I would just pretend that one of the unknowns (say, $x$) is actually known and solve for the rest.

Comment: Actually, I would write the equations as
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rrrc}
(1-a)x&+3y&-4z&=0\\
x&-(3+a)y&+5z&=0\\
3x&+y&-az& = 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
or in the matrix form
$$
\left[
\begin{array}{rrrc}
(1-a)&3&-4\\
1&-(3+a)&5\\
3&1&-a
\end{array}
\right]
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{array}
\right]
= \left[
\begin{array}{c}
0 \\ 0 \\ 0
\end{array}
\right]
$$
Now the question becomes: Is there a non-trivial solution to this equation?